# Heine–Borel theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've seen that the set is closed and bounded $\iff$ compactness.

However, there are some examples in other posts illustrate there may have closed and bounded sets need not be compact. That's a bit confusing.

I am sure I've missed something important. Please enlighten me.

Comment: It holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the standard topology/metric) but may fail for other spaces.

Comment: @user722227 Would you please give some examples space that it fails, does this also holds for infinity space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have missed the fact that compactness is equivalent to being closed and bounded holds in $\Bbb R^n$, but not in general. For instance, it doesn't hold in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

This holds for finite-dimensional normed vector spaces (like $\mathbb{R}^n$ with any of its norms).

The following result says that this need not be true for other spaces:

> Let $V$ be a vector space with norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$. Then the unit
>   ball $\{v \in V: \Vert v \Vert \leq 1\}$ (which is clearly closed and
>   bounded) is compact if and only if $\dim V < \infty$.

Comment: Would you please further enlighten me on why does it has to be finite?